# Nested while loop with trailer values

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, while-loop, nested-loops

The purpose of my program is to be a virtual McDonalds cashier.  The first part of my program lets the cashier take one customers order.  Thanks to the while loop the customer can order as many items as he/she wants. In the end it displays the tax, subtotal, and final bill.  Along with how much the user pays with and their change.  Now I need my program to do all of the first part, but I need the user/cashier to do this for as many customers that are in line.  I tried nest the two while loops together, but I'm doing something wrong and I don't know what.  Can someone help me?  By the way, the first part works 100%.

## first part

```
num1 = 4.87
num2 = 5.03
num3 = 5.50
num4 = 9.45
num5 = 1.29
num6 = 2.19
num7 = 2.29
itemnum = 0
Subtotal = 0
tax = 0.0565
amtgiven = 0
change = 0
quantity = 0
foodprice = 0
Totalprice1 = 0
Totalprice2 = 0
Totalprice3 = 0
Totalprice4 = 0
Totalprice5 = 0
Totalprice6 = 0
Totalprice7 = 0
billtax = 0
finalbill = 0
change = 0

print "Welcome to Virtual McDonald's!"   "Would you like to order a food item"
print "Item:                     Meal/tem:                          Price:"
print "1                          Big Mac Meal                        4.87"
print "2                          Quarter Pounder Meal                5.03"
print "3                          Chicken Nuggets Meal (5 piece)      5.50"
print "4                          ChickenNuggets Meal (10 piece)      9.45"
print "5                          Apple Pie                           1.29"
print "6                          Large Drink                         2.19"
print "7                          Large Fries                         2.29"

itemnum = input("Enter the item you would like to purchase! ")
quantity = input("How many of this item do you want?")
while itemnum != -1:

    if itemnum == 1:
        foodprice = quantity * num1
        Totalprice1 = foodprice

    if itemnum == 2:
        foodprice = quantity * num2
        Totalprice2 = foodprice

    if itemnum == 3:
        foodprice = quantity * num3
        Totalprice3 = foodprice

    if itemnum == 4:
        foodprice == quantity * num4
        Totalprice4 = foodprice

    if itemnum == 5:
        foodprice = quantity * num5
        Totalprice5 = foodprice

    if itemnum == 6:
        foodprice == quantity * num6
        Totalprice6 = foodprice

    if itemnum == 7:
        foodprice = quantity * num7
        Totalprice7 = foodprice   

    subtotal = Totalprice1 + Totalprice2 + Totalprice3 + Totalprice4 + Totalprice5 + Totalprice6 + Totalprice7 
    billtax = subtotal * tax
    finalbill = subtotal + billtax
    itemnum = input("Enter the item you would like to purchase! ")
    quantity = input("How many of this item do you want?")

print "Your total bill without tax is... ", round(subtotal,2)
print "Your total tax is... ", round(billtax,2)
print "Your final bill is... ", round(finalbill,2)
amtgiven = input ("How much do you want to pay with?")
change = amtgiven - finalbill
print "Your change is... ", round(change,2)
```

## second part

```
num1 = 4.87
num2 = 5.03
num3 = 5.50
num4 = 9.45
num5 = 1.29
num6 = 2.19
num7 = 2.29
itemnum = 0
Subtotal = 0
tax = 0.0565
amtgiven = 0
change = 0
quantity = 0
foodprice = 0
Totalprice1 = 0
Totalprice2 = 0
Totalprice3 = 0
Totalprice4 = 0
Totalprice5 = 0
Totalprice6 = 0
Totalprice7 = 0
billtax = 0
finalbill = 0
change = 0
customer = 0

print "Welcome to Virtual McDonald's!"   "Would you like to order a food item"
print "Item:                     Meal/tem:                          Price:"
print "1                          Big Mac Meal                        4.87"
print "2                          Quarter Pounder Meal                5.03"
print "3                          Chicken Nuggets Meal (5 piece)      5.50"
print "4                          ChickenNuggets Meal (10 piece)      9.45"
print "5                          Apple Pie                           1.29"
print "6                          Large Drink                         2.19"
print "7                          Large Fries                         2.29"


customer = raw_input ("Would you like to order? (If not type No)")
while customer != "No":

    while itemnum != -1: 
        itemnum = input("Enter the item you would like to purchase! ")
        quantity = input("How many of this item do you want? ")

        if itemnum == 1:
            foodprice = quantity * num1
            Totalprice1 = Totalprice1 + foodprice

        if itemnum == 2:
            foodprice = quantity * num2
            Totalprice2 = Totalprice2 + foodprice

        if itemnum == 3:
            foodprice = quantity * num3
            Totalprice3 = Totalprice3 + foodprice

        if itemnum == 4:
            foodprice = quantity * num4
            Totalprice4 = Totalprice4 + foodprice

        if itemnum == 5:
            foodprice = quantity * num5
            Totalprice5 = Totalprice5 + foodprice

        if itemnum == 6:
            foodprice = quantity * num6
            Totalprice6 = Totalprice6 + foodprice

        if itemnum == 7:
            foodprice = quantity * num7
            Totalprice7 = Totalprice7 + foodprice

    itemnum = input("Enter the item you would like to purchase! ")
    quantity = input("How many of this item do you want? ")
    subtotal = Totalprice1 + Totalprice2 + Totalprice3 + Totalprice4 + Totalprice5 + Totalprice6 + Totalprice7 
    billtax = subtotal * tax
    finalbill = subtotal + billtax        
    print "Your total bill without tax is... ", round(subtotal,2)
    print "Your total tax is... ", round(billtax,2)
    print "Your final bill is... ", round(finalbill,2)
    amtgiven = input ("How much do you want to pay with? ")
    change = amtgiven - finalbill
    print "Your change is... ", round(change,2)
    customer = raw_input ("Would you like to order? (If not type No)")
```

#output

When I run the second program this is what outputs:

```
Welcome to Virtual McDonald's!Would you like to order a food item
Item:                     Meal/tem:                          Price:
1                          Big Mac Meal                        4.87
2                          Quarter Pounder Meal                5.03
3                          Chicken Nuggets Meal (5 piece)      5.50
4                          ChickenNuggets Meal (10 piece)      9.45
5                          Apple Pie                           1.29
6                          Large Drink                         2.19
7                          Large Fries                         2.29
Would you like to order? (If not type No) yes
Enter the item you would like to purchase! 1
How many of this item do you want? 2
Enter the item you would like to purchase! 1
How many of this item do you want? 4
Your total bill without tax is...  9.74
Your total tax is...  0.55
Your final bill is...  10.29
How much do you want to pay with? 11
Your change is...  0.71
Enter the item you would like to purchase!
```

(After entering a few menu items the program stops running the loop and goes straight to the bill.  Also after the bill it doesn't ask the user if they're is another customer.)

When I run the first part this is what outputs:

```
Welcome to Virtual McDonald's!Would you like to order a food item
Item:                     Meal/tem:                          Price:
1                          Big Mac Meal                        4.87
2                          Quarter Pounder Meal                5.03
3                          Chicken Nuggets Meal (5 piece)      5.50
4                          ChickenNuggets Meal (10 piece)      9.45
5                          Apple Pie                           1.29
6                          Large Drink                         2.19
7                          Large Fries                         2.29
Enter the item you would like to purchase! 1
How many of this item do you want?4
Enter the item you would like to purchase! 2
How many of this item do you want?1
Enter the item you would like to purchase! -1
How many of this item do you want?-1
Your total bill without tax is...  24.51
Your total tax is...  1.38
Your final bill is...  25.89
How much do you want to pay with? 26
Your change is...  0.11
```

I want the second part to output what the first part outputted.  Except after it gives the customer his/her change I want it to execute the other loop, therefore asking the user is there another customer.  If the user inputs "yes" then the program will run all over again for another customer.  Only when there is no more customers does the user input "No" to end the program.  (I went to the python shell and copied these output results.  Numbers on the right are the numbers I entered.)

Comment: If you can't understand the question/description, maybe you can copy and past the code into python 2.7.3 and go from there.

Comment: You should show what the output is now, and what you think it should be.  A simple copy/paste of a run of your app, showing what goes wrong, should do it, with a brief explanation

Comment: @lxop I did it.  Do you think it is more informative now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there were a few things that could be fixed with your program, grammatically and logically. I went ahead and fixed them and I'll explain what I did and why. First of all, You need another `while` loop in order to satisfy your need for the user to designate whether or not another customer was in line. I made a new variable to handle the new `while` loop. Here is the code for that:

```
nextcustomer = "yes"    
while nextcustomer != "no":
    amtgiven = 0
    change = 0
    quantity = 0
    foodprice = 0
    totalprice = 0
    billtax = 0
    finalbill = 0
    itemnum = 0
```

Within this new loop, however, we need to add some variables that will need to reset after each customer. The global variables outside the loop should be the ones that won't need to change from customer to customer, those being the price of the food or the tax rate. We will need to add in the change and the totalprice and those things and I did so in the previous code.

Also the question of whether there will be another customer or not will go inside the first while loop, after all the other stuff has happened so that it knows whether to iterate again or not. That question is here:

```
while nextcustomer != "no":
    (all of the code)
    nextcustomer = raw_input("Is there another customer? (yes or no) ")
```

I added a few breaks as well with the second while loop or else it would keep iterating without being able to prompt the user if they wanted to order or not.

Another change I made was I consolidated all of your `Totalprice1, Totalprice2`...variables into one variable `totalprice`. You only need one variable for this because you have the prices defined in their own variables already (`num1, num2`...). The code for the counter variable under each selection looks like this:

```
totalprice += foodprice
```

This is equivalent to `totalprice = totalprice + foodprice`. It is just nicer syntax. Also now you don't even need a `subtotal` variable.

I also added an `if` statement after the question of what number they chose that picks up if they entered a -1 so that you don't have to enter the amount of the -1 item:

```
if itemnum == -1:
    break
```

There were a few more changes I'm sure, I may come back and edit this to make sure it's all explained but here's the full program's code after editing:

```
num1 = 4.87
num2 = 5.03
num3 = 5.50
num4 = 9.45
num5 = 1.29
num6 = 2.19
num7 = 2.29
tax = 0.0565
customer = 0
nextcustomer = "yes"
while nextcustomer != "no":
    amtgiven = 0
    change = 0
    quantity = 0
    foodprice = 0
    totalprice = 0
    billtax = 0
    finalbill = 0
    itemnum = 0
    print "Welcome to Virtual McDonald's!"
    print "Item:                     Meal/item:                          Price:"
    print "1                          Big Mac Meal                        4.87"
    print "2                          Quarter Pounder Meal                5.03"
    print "3                          Chicken Nuggets Meal (5 piece)      5.50"
    print "4                          ChickenNuggets Meal (10 piece)      9.45"
    print "5                          Apple Pie                           1.29"
    print "6                          Large Drink                         2.19"
    print "7                          Large Fries                         2.29"

    customer = raw_input ("Would you like to order? (If not type no)")
    while customer != "no":

        while itemnum != -1: 
            itemnum = input("Enter the item you would like to purchase! ")
            if itemnum == -1:
                break
            quantity = input("How many of this item do you want? ")

            if itemnum == 1:
                foodprice = quantity * num1
                totalprice += foodprice

            elif itemnum == 2:
                foodprice = quantity * num2
                totalprice += foodprice

            elif itemnum == 3:
                foodprice = quantity * num3
                totalprice += foodprice

            elif itemnum == 4:
                foodprice = quantity * num4
                totalprice += foodprice

            elif itemnum == 5:
                foodprice = quantity * num5
                totalprice += foodprice

            elif itemnum == 6:
                foodprice = quantity * num6
                totalprice += foodprice

            elif itemnum == 7:
                foodprice = quantity * num7
                totalprice += foodprice

        billtax = totalprice * tax
        finalbill = totalprice + billtax        
        print "Your total bill without tax is... ", round(totalprice,2)
        print "Your total tax is... ", round(billtax,2)
        print "Your final bill is... ", round(finalbill,2)
        amtgiven = input("How much do you want to pay with? ")
        change = amtgiven - finalbill
        print "Your change is... ", round(change,2)
        break
    nextcustomer = raw_input("Is there another customer? (yes or no) ")
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: honestly right now I want to give you a big hug!!!  Yes it solves my problem!  I can't beleive it.   Out of that whole program you only had one thing wrong.  When it printed the tax it was printing the price.  Easy fix :)

Comment: Now the last part of my assignment is to take all of the sales, tax, and "finalbills" and total them.   I think I can do that part though.  I sat and looked at this program for a couple hours and I couldn't find a solution. thanks man.

Comment: Good, I'm glad I could help, it's an interesting business nesting loops